# Recursive Merge Sorting results in same as original

Tags: java

I'm working on a merge sort that sorts and int[]. My mergeSort method takes in the array, startindex, and endindex. I'm also outputting the before and after in main method. The after array results in the same as the before. I don't see what I'm doing wrong with my alg. I've been looking up what other people have said on doing merge sorts and it looks like I'm doing it right. Clearly not though as the list is not sorting.. What am I doing wrong in my algorithm of merge sort?

UPDATE: So I've made some changes to my code and it seems the dividing process is working fine but when merging the code doesn't merge the sorted lists. Instead it just sorts using the original ones that was divided into. This can be seen in the last step of merging. The two arrays that it is merging should be sorted, that way when you compare each index one by one the smaller one of the two should be placed into the new list and in the right order.

the two lists being merged are {2 3 2 52 64 2} & {1 8 54 8 32 7 } which is the same as the original {2 3 2 52 64 2 1 8 54 8 32 7} just divided into 2.

NEW CODE:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int [] array = {2,3,2,52,64,2,1,8,54,8,32,7};

    int[] newarray = mergeSort(array, 0 ,array.length);


    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Unsorted List:");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.println("Sorted List:");
    for (int i = 0; i < newarray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(newarray[i] + " ");
    }
}


public static int[] mergeSort(int[] list, int start, int end) {
    if ((end-start) <= 1) {
        return list;
    }

        int mid = (start+end)/2;

        mergeSort(list, start, mid);
        mergeSort(list, mid, end);
        return merge(list, start, mid, end);
        //return list;
    }

public static int[] merge(int[]list, int start, int mid, int end) {
    int[] tempList = new int[list.length];

    System.out.println("First half");
    for (int i = start; i < mid; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Second half");
    for (int i = mid; i < end; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    int i=start;
    int j=mid;
    int k=0;


    while (i < mid && j < end) {
        if (list[i] <= list[j]) {
            tempList[k] = list[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            tempList[k] = list[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    while (i < mid) {
        tempList[k] = list[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    while (j < end) {
        tempList[k] = list[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    System.out.println("Merged");
    for (int z= 0 ; z < tempList.length; z++) {
        System.out.print(tempList[z] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    return tempList;
}
```

CONSOLE OUTPUT:
First half
3 
Second half
2
Merged
2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
2
Second half
3 2
Merged
2 3 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
64
Second half
2
Merged
2 64 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
52
Second half
64 2
Merged
52 64 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
2 3 2
Second half
52 64 2
Merged
2 3 2 52 64 2 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
8
Second half
54
Merged
8 54 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
1
Second half
8 54
Merged
1 8 54 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
32
Second half
7
Merged
7 32 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
8
Second half
32 7
Merged
8 32 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
1 8 54
Second half
8 32 7
Merged
1 8 8 32 7 54 0 0 0 0 0 0

First half
2 3 2 52 64 2
Second half
1 8 54 8 32 7
Merged
1 2 3 2 8 52 54 8 32 7 64 2

Unsorted List:
2 3 2 52 64 2 1 8 54 8 32 7

Sorted List:
1 2 3 2 8 52 54 8 32 7 64 2

Comment: The code that you've posted won't compile. Please test before posting.

Comment: At the end of merge(), rather than return templist[], copy templist[] back to list[].

Comment: @rcgldr Should I keep the return list[] in mergeSort()?

Comment: It would be best to have a separate entry function called by the user. This entry function would do a one time allocation of templist, which would be passed as a parameter to mergeSort() and merge(). Once the sort is done, the entry function would free templist. With this implementation, you can eliminate the copy back operations by having the merge direction change with level of recursion, either via a boolean parameter in mergeSort(), or by having two instances of mergeSort(), one where data ends up in list, one where data ends up in templist. I can explain later if interested.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ...
It is a recursion process with divide and conquer algorithm, so it can be difficult to understand.
If you do not know what algorithm it is based please visit [merge sort algorith {easy for understanding with figure}](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_structures_algorithms/merge_sort_algorithm.htm)

**1. Overview**

The Mergesort algorithm can be used to sort a collection of objects. Mergesort is a so called divide and conquer algorithm. *Divide and conquer algorithms* divide the original data into smaller sets of data to solve the problem.

**2. Mergesort**

During the Mergesort process the objects of the collection are divided into two collections. To split a collection, Mergesort will take the middle of the collection and split the collection into its left and its right part.

The resulting collections are again recursively sorted via the Mergesort algorithm.

Once the sorting process of the two collections is finished, the result of the two collections is combined. To combine both collections Mergesort starts in each collection at the beginning. It picks the object which is smaller and inserts this object into the new collection. For this collection it now selects the next elements and selects the smaller element from both collections.

Once all elements from both collections have been inserted in the new collection, Mergesort has successfully sorted the collection.

To avoid the creation of too many collections, typically one new collection is created and the left and right side are treated as different collections.

[image: merge sort resursion]

**3. Implementation**

Create the following program.

```
public class Mergesort {
    private int[] numbers;
    private int[] helper;

    private int number;

    public void sort(int[] values) {
            this.numbers = values;
            number = values.length;
            this.helper = new int[number];
            mergesort(0, number - 1);
    }

    private void mergesort(int low, int high) {
            // check if low is smaller then high, if not then the array is sorted
            if (low < high) {
                    // Get the index of the element which is in the middle
                    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
                    // Sort the left side of the array
                    mergesort(low, middle);
                    // Sort the right side of the array
                    mergesort(middle + 1, high);
                    // Combine them both
                    merge(low, middle, high);
            }
    }

    private void merge(int low, int middle, int high) {

            // Copy both parts into the helper array
            for (int i = low; i <= high; i++) {
                    helper[i] = numbers[i];
            }

            int i = low;
            int j = middle + 1;
            int k = low;
            // Copy the smallest values from either the left or the right side back
            // to the original array
            while (i <= middle && j <= high) {
                    if (helper[i] <= helper[j]) {
                            numbers[k] = helper[i];
                            i++;
                    } else {
                            numbers[k] = helper[j];
                            j++;
                    }
                    k++;
            }
            // Copy the rest of the left side of the array into the target array
            while (i <= middle) {
                    numbers[k] = helper[i];
                    k++;
                    i++;
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: None of this explains why the OP is seeing the output he is.